# How to get CKRecord info from CKDatabaseNotification while perform changes on shared database?

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

This is `userInfo` I receive from server when change one property:

```
[AnyHashable("aps"): {
    "content-available" = 1;
}, AnyHashable("ck"): {
    ce = 2;
    cid = "iCloud.pl.blueworld.fieldservice";
    met =     {
        dbs = 3;
        sid = "E93874B3-53B4-4CD7-83A0-157DDE3B1094";
        zid = fieldservice;
        zoid = "_c42e727205f9a1c05eab6df6298d51ca";
    };
    nid = "46a3d259-11c5-4212-9bef-b9aef4ea5bf8";
}]
```

I can quickly create object:

```
CKNotification(fromRemoteNotificationDictionary: userInfo)
```

but now how can I receive its record ID? I need to perform changes on UI, but need to know what object has been changed.

Comment: Try to cast CKNotification to CKQueryNotification. This class has recordID property.

Comment: casting fails... success with casting only as CKDatabase...