# Query Changes after receiving CKDatabaseNotification

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cloudkit

I'm currently building an app that allows user to share events and check in their guests simultaneously using multiple phones. I managed to set up CKQuerySubscription and update, delete and create works fine but only on the primary phone (the one sharing the event).

I recently found out that for a non-primary user to get notifications, it has to get notifications from CKDatabaseNotification which i set up and it works as I am getting remote notifications when I make changes through CloudKit Dashboard.

But the notification i get (CKDatabaseNotification) does not come with anything that would allow me to find what records changed. I've tried casting it as CKNotification as suggested on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45711832/how-to-get-ckrecord-info-from-ckdatabasenotification-while-perform-changes-on-sh) but as expected it fails.

I have a custom zone set up and my questions are as below:

- How do I get any information about what changed from a CKDatabaseNotification?
- Am I even doing that the right way? I've read somewhere else as well that some people managed to set up subscription through CKQuerySubscription on a shared database as long as it is on a custom zone, which I have but my codes told me subscription failed.

Comment: See `applicationDidReceiveRemoteNotification` method in https://github.com/maxvol/RxCloudKit/blob/master/RxCloudKit/Cache.swift

Comment: So here an idea. Create a meta record in your database in which you store the changes and when you get a CKDatabaseNotification, check your meta record.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CKDatabaseNotification will only tell you that something has changed, not what it is.  The recommended path forward is you use a CKFetchDatabaseChangesOperation to find out what record zones have changes.  Then you use the record zone IDs from that operation in a CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation to get all the changes.

There's a bit more information in the [CloudKit Quick Start Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/MaintainingaLocalCacheofCloudKitRecords/MaintainingaLocalCacheofCloudKitRecords.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014987-CH12-SW7)

I'm cherry picking some relevant info below:

> After app launch or the receipt of a push, your app uses CKFetchDatabaseChangesOperation and then CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation to ask the server for only the changes since the last time it updated.
>
> The key to these operations is the previousServerChangeToken object,
>   which tells the server when your app last spoke to the server,
>   allowing the server to return only the items that were changed since
>   that time.
>
> First your app will use a CKFetchDatabaseChangesOperation to find out
>   which zones have changed

Then

> Next your app uses a CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation object with the
>   set of zone IDs you just collected to do the following:
>
> • Create and update any changed records 
>   • Delete any records that no longer exist
>   • Update the zone change tokens

The WWDC video [CloudKit Best Practices](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/231) addresses this topic as well.

Comment: Actually used this method to get the changes. Just forgot to update that I found the solution here. Thanks